# Remove specific word from HTML-element given the text decoration tags

Tags: javascript, html, dom, contenteditable

I have a contenteditable element with some text inside decorated with `<b>` and `<i>` tags. I am trying to find the best way to delete the last word from it without affecting the decoration. 
I can't simply remove the last word in the last child node because one word can be contained in several `<b>` and `<i>` tags.

For example (the word "internet." must be removed):

```
<div>Build the best reference material for developer tools <i>on the inter<b>net</b></i>.</div>
```

Maybe there is some more or less elegant and native solution for this case.

Comment: Do you mean an actual _word_ as specified by the natural language rules/conventions - or basically just “everything after the last white space”?

Comment: @CBroe yes, I mean an actual word just like in the example

Comment: That does not actually answer my question. Your example would match both.

Comment: I am sorry then, by 'word' I mean everything separated by space

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code that will help you to achieve what you are looking for. Instead of using HTML, use text and that would solve the problem.

```js
var text = $("#sometext").text();
text = text.split(" ");
text.pop();  //remove last element

$(".output").html(text.join(" "));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sometext">Build the best reference material for developer tools <i>on the inter<b>net</b></i>.</div>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: he asked only to remove the last word not the decoration elements

Comment: this code is removing all decoration tags by replacing element inner HTML with plain text, that's not what I need